# C: struct->char *: contents changed: can someone explain this?

Tags: c, string, pointers

Just to give some context, I have an assignment for my computer networks class to read an input file and packetize the contents. So I have functions to initialize pointers to data related to each layer.
I'm not having any issues with the design of the assignment but rather an extremely obscure bug that I am dealing with...

I have included relevant structure definitions and the lines of code leading up to the bug...The area's enclosed by `//******************`'s is where the bug occurs. Some how the output of the first `printf` is different from the output of the second `printf` despite referencing the same pointer... I don't even touch the pointer so I'm having a hard time figuring out why the contents go bad all of a sudden...

I have also included the `printf` outputs...

```
typedef struct
{
  char *data;
  int size;
} layer4_t;

typedef struct
{
  char *data;
  int nframes;
  int overflow;
  int size;
} layer3_t;

layer4_t *layer4_initForTransmit( const char *str )
{
  //
  // output variable initialization
  // 
  layer4_t *y = malloc( sizeof( layer4_t ) );
  if (!y) fprintf( stderr, "transmit: layer4: error: malloc failed\n");

  // compute size of the data buffer (+1 for null byte)
  y->size = strlen(str);
  // memory allocation of (layer4)y.data
  y->data = malloc( sizeof( y->size+1 )); // ******** INCRIMINATING... 
  // copy contents of str to buf and copy over null byte
  y->data[0] = '\0';
  strcat( y->data, str );

  if (DEBUG) printLayerData( y, 4 );

  return y;
}

layer3_t *layer3_initForTransmit( layer4_t *x )
{
  //
  // variable declarations
  //

  // 2. output variable
  layer3_t *y;

  // dummy ptrs
  char *ptr;     // 6 
  char *buf_ptr; // 1

  // 7. i: frame index, 
  // 3. n_frames: number of frames, 
  // 5. tx_size: size of transmission buffer, 
  // 1. buf_size: size of the layer4 data;
  // 8. offset: used to offset the buf_ptr
  int i, n_frames, tx_size, buf_size, offset = 0;

  //
  // variable assignments
  //

  // 1. assign dummy pointers
  buf_ptr = x->data;
  buf_size = x->size;

  // **********************
  printf( "%s\n", x->data );

  // 2. allocate space for output variable
  y = malloc( sizeof( layer3_t ));

  // 3. calculate number of frames
  y->nframes = n_frames = buf_size / MSS;   

  // 4. overflow = sizeof(layer4.data) mod MSS + layer3 header size
  y->overflow = buf_size % MSS + LAYER_3_HEAD_SIZE;

  // 5. calculate size of tx (transmission) buffer
  y->size = tx_size = LAYER_3_FRAME_SIZE * n_frames + y->overflow;

  // 6. allocate and confirm space for tx buffer
  y->data = ptr = malloc( tx_size+1 ); // +1 for null byte
  if (!ptr) fprintf( stderr, "transmit: layer3: error: malloc failed\n");

  printf( "%s\n", x->data );
  // **********************
...
```

---

```
output:

// first printf
this is a string of characters in the file sendfile.txt. willy wonka is a
fictional character in roald dahl's novel Charlie and the Chocolate Factory.
Willy Wonka is a manufacturer of premier brand chocolates and is planning to
retire soon. In anticipation of this, he begins a competition to find his
successor of the chocolate factory.
the way willy wonka intended on finding his successor was by throwing a contest
for 5 people to find a golden ticket inside one of his chocolate products.
?

// second printf
this is a string?/`3?
```

Comment: It's got to be an overwrite somewhere, which could have occurred before this function was called. The section you commented looks fairly benign. Before you ever read anything into `data` how much space did you allocate for it? If it wasn't enough, then subsequent allocations and writes could be accessing pieces of memory being used (improperly) through `x->data`. Maybe you could show that part of the code.

Comment: I agree with 'mbratch': your 'x->data' must be on the stack and overwritten by the local variables in this function.

Comment: `y->data = ptr = malloc( tx_size+1 ); // +1 for null byte` x-data is allocated but never filled with anything useful.

Comment: @mbratch i found the error, it was in the layer4_init function...i've also edited the post and added the incriminating lines of code...thanks alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sizeof( y->size+1 )
```

should be:

```
y->size+1
```

sizeof(any int) is always the same value (4 on Windows, 4 on most Linux systems, might be different on others) and is the same as `sizeof(int)`. You don't want to allocate enough space for an int, you want to allocate `y->size+1` bytes.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're dealing with a memory leak.  It's likely that the value in x->data is getting clobbered by your operations on y.  Depending on when the original x (passed in) and y were allocated they could be next to each other on the heap.  Test the value of x->data after each operation on y.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks for the response! i've tried printf'ing x->data after each operation and I think you're right about x getting affected by operations on y... but how can i fix this??

Comment: You have to find the memory leak.  You're managing your own memory with malloc so somewhere you're writing outside of that memory space.  It could be that you're not casting correctly and you're writing a double (8 bytes) to space allocated for an int (4 bytes).  But it helps to know exactly where you're corrupting the x struct's memory.  Also, I agree wiht @alexeypolo that you need to check that y != null to ensure you were allocated memory but unless you're using all your RAM and hard drive you should almost always get memory allocated to you.

Answer (score 0):

"x" is a pointer known outside of this function. Maybe someone touches this pointer ? In another thread ?

Also, there is a minor bug, you do not check return value of the first malloc call:

```
y = malloc( sizeof( layer3_t ))
```

Comment: thanks for the catch. i've done the proper check to the return value of malloc.
this program does not implement any threading and note that x is declared as a parameter to this function